# References in latex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

How can I write like the references below in latex?

I want just an example to show me how can I create spaces. For example in the first reference: how create spaces in the second and third line.

Any help will be very appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no numbering, the references must be identified in the text by name and year. Therefore we can guess that this bibliography is used for Harvard style referencing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\begin{document}
\cite{Amos80}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Here is the file test.bib.

```
@Article{Amos80,
  author =       {Amos, D. E.},
  title =        {Computation of Exponential Integrals},
  journal =      toms,
  year =         {1980},
  volume =       {6},
  number =       {3},
  pages =        {365--377}
}
```

[image: harvard]

Comment: You may want to mention that "Harvard style" referencing is also known as "author-year style" referencing. In addition to the `harvard` package, the `natbib` and `apacite` can deliver authoryear-style citation call-outs as well.

Comment: In case if we have several references, the Harvard system always put the references by authors alphabetical order ???

Comment: @Christina - You can easily obtain an answer to your question yourself by creating a bib file, choosing a bibliography style that supports authoryear-style citations, and running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.